# winsound in python - low latency on monitor, high latency on laptop why?

Tags: python, audio, latency, beep, winsound

I am using winsound to play a short sound

```
frequency = 800 
duration = 10 
winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

The code is in an endless loop in a condition. If the condition is True, the sound plays.

I am on Windows 10.

Everything works well, if I have an external monitor connected and I play the sound through the speakers of the monitor.

If I play the sound through the speakers of my laptop, it has a terrible latency > 1 s.

What can be the problem? It is the same sound card in both cases isn't it?